# Show error message for controls using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Script : Jquery
I am new to jquery, and I found this piece of code which I tried but didn't succeed. It uses jquery validator plugin. Here is the code :

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="employment-application" method="post">

    <input name="full_name" type="text" />
    <div id="full_name_validate"></div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(function validate() {

    var rules = {
        rules: {
            full_name: {
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 50,
                required: true
            },
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var name = $(element).attr("name");
            error.appendTo($("#" + name + "_validate"));
        },
    };

    $('#employment-application').validate(rules);

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I achieve this ? here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/cMhQ7/

Comment: its working in jsfiddle link u submitted. not sure what you are expecting. the first time it validates will be when u are loosing focus of the field.

Comment: I want the same output in the code , i have provided. I don't know where am I going wrong, whether I am missing any plugins, no idea. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="employment-application" method="post">
    <input name="full_name" type="text" />
    <div id="full_name_validate"></div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function validate() {

    var rules = {
        rules: {
            full_name: {
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 50,
                required: true
            },
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var name = $(element).attr("name");
            error.appendTo($("#" + name + "_validate"));
        },
    };

    $('#employment-application').validate(rules);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like the validator plugin version you are using is causing the issue. Try the following one http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js

or any from the page [jqueryvalidation.org hotlink](http://jqueryvalidation.org/#1-13-1-files-on-microsoft-s-ajax-cdn-(hotlinking-welcome):)

I hope this fixes the issue.